# Message queue solution for activities that come and go on Android?

Tags: android, message-queue, android-service

Lets say I have a Service S and Activity A. S downloads data for A (or handles some long running work, whatever), but A is not always present. I don't want S to hang around when it's job queue is empty: S should post the results of the finished works to some kind of a mailbox for A, so A can pull the messages when it comes back again.

Can this be achieved without using SQLite of file storage for the implementation of the mailbox? I'd prefer some faster mechanism, write operations tend to be quite slow on a device. I thought about using a simple static list inside the ApplicationContext, but afaik relying on the ApplicationContext results a risky/fragile solution.

Could anyone recommend a pattern for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can this be achieved without using SQLite of file storage for the implementation of the mailbox?

Not reliably. Either it's a file, or it might be nuked before A comes back again. Remember that your process -- where all your static data members and the `Application` object reside -- does not live forever. Once S shuts down (which is a *good* thing, thanks!), Android is welcome to terminate the process, taking your "mailbox" with you if it is solely in RAM.

You could persist it to disk yet keep a singleton or something around as a cache, so if A returns quickly you can skip some of the I/O. Or, if it does not really matter much if the messages exist for A, you could keep them in RAM and simply shrug your shoulders if the process gets terminated first.